# Paypal Adaptive Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are integrating the Adaptive Payments to receive payment from one user and parallel payment to two user's accounts. Now as per the PayPal guide this is now deprecated the https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#link-adaptivepaymentsactorsandobjects .
So is there any other alternative to achieve the same in PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Current PayPal Checkouts must be to a single receiver account.